# how to show thumb path photos in php

Tags: php, directory, dir

how to show thumb folder images in php

i have a folder name albums
and in album each folder have photos & thumb folder photos

example

- uae/thumb/1.jpg
- uae/1.jpg
- uk/thumb/1.jpg
- uk/1.jpg
- usa/thumb/1.jpg
- usa/1.jpg

and my code is showing  this photos only

- usa/1.jpg
- uk/1.jpg
- uae/1.jpg

and i want to show only thumb photos

- usa/thumb/1.jpg
- uk/thumb/1.jpg
- uae/thumb/1.jpg

how can i do this 
please help me to fix this issue 
thanks in advance

here is code

```
<?php

    //path to directory to scan. i have included a wildcard for a subdirectory
    $directory = "albums/*/";

    //get all image files with a .jpg extension.
    $images = glob("" . $directory . "*.jpg");

array_multisort(array_map('filemtime', $images), SORT_DESC, $images);

?>

<?php $num_of_files = 0; $i=0; foreach ($images as $image):?>
<div class="item"><a href="<?php echo basename(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_DIRNAME)); ?>.html" target="_blank">
<img class="lazyOwl" src="<?php echo $image ?>" />
<p><?php echo basename(pathinfo($image, PATHINFO_DIRNAME)); ?></p>
             </div>
<?php if (++$num_of_files == 3)break; ?>
  <?php if(++$i%3==0): ?>

<?php endif ?>

<?php endforeach ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adjust your directory path:

```
$directory = "albums/*/thumb/";

//get all image files with a .jpg extension.
$images = glob($directory . "*.jpg");
```

... or try using `SPL` tools:

```
$directory = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('albums/*/'); // or ('albums/*')
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($directory);
$images = new RegexIterator($iterator, '/thumb\/\(.jpe?g|.png)$/i', RecursiveRegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
$images = iterator_to_array($images);
...
// iterating over $images
```

Comment: i replace it but no result it is showing blank page

Comment: @user1542571, try additional approach from above

Comment: thanks for reply but i update my code but it is showing some error Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'UnexpectedValueException' with message 'RecursiveDirectoryIterator::__construct(albums/*/,albums/*/) [<a href='recursivedirectoryiterator.--construct'>recursivedirectoryiterator.--construct</a>]: No error' in C:\xampp\htdocs\gallery\demo.php:10 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\gallery\demo.php(10): RecursiveDirectoryIterator->__construct('albums/*/') #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\gallery\demo.php on line 10

Comment: can you put your in my code because i am not good in php thanks

Comment: its spelling mistake i just check my thumb folder name is thumbs so now its is working fine thanks for the answer

Comment: but directory name is not found all album name is thumbs how can i fix it help me plz

Comment: what 'directory name'? show the full error message. P.S. Make sure that your current php-script has proper access to image directory